# Command handler - message is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

As of late, I've been starting a new bot based on old code as a learning experience. As you can imagine, it's a bit of troubleshooting. My command handler is based off of 3 things: functions.js, app.js, and files that have commands. I'm experiencing problems with the help command
My command handler and other things:

```
// Calling Packages
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const client = new Discord.Client();
const weather = require('weather-js');
const fs = require('fs');

const {ping: func} = require("C:/Users/LeviB/Desktop/Folders/Downloads, Setup, and Uninstall Files/Code/Discord Bots/WelcomeGoodbyeQuickDB/functions.js")

const commands = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Storage/commands.json', 'utf8'))

// Global Settings
const prefix = 'cb!';

// Listener Event One
bot.on('message', message => {

    // Variables
    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    let sender = message.author;
    let cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
    let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (sender.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

//Command Handler
try {

    let commandFile = require(`./commands/${cmd}.js`);
    commandFile.run(bot, message, args, func);

} catch(e) {

    console.log(e.message);

} finally {

    console.log(`${message.author.username} ran the command: ${cmd}`);

}
```

My functions file

```
    help: function(channel) {


        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor(0x1D82B6)



        let commandsFound = 0;

        for (var cmd in commands) {

            if (commands[cmd].group.toUpperCase() === 'USER') {
                commandsFound++

                embed.addField(`${commands[cmd].name}`, `**Description:** ${commands[cmd].desc}\n**Usage:** ${prefix + commands[cmd].usage}`);
            }


        }

        embed.setFooter(`Currently showing user commands. To view another group do ${prefix}help [group / command]`)
        embed.setDescription(`**${commandsFound} commands found** - <> means required, [] means optional`)

        message.author.send({embed})
        message.channel.send({embed: {
            color: 0x1D82B6,
            description: `**Check your DMs ${message.author}!**`
        }})
        },
    }
```

And the command I'm trying to run:

```
let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
let sender = message.author;
let cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");


exports.run = (bot, message, args, func) => {

    console.log('ok i hate this')

    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x1D82B6)



    let commandsFound = 0;

    for (var cmd in commands) {

        if (commands[cmd].group.toUpperCase() === 'USER') {
            commandsFound++

            embed.addField(`${commands[cmd].name}`, `**Description:** ${commands[cmd].desc}\n**Usage:** ${prefix + commands[cmd].usage}`);
        }


    }

    embed.setFooter(`Currently showing user commands. To view another group do ${prefix}help [group / command]`)
    embed.setDescription(`**${commandsFound} commands found** - <> means required, [] means optional`)

    msg.author.send({embed})
    msg.channel.send({embed: {
        color: 0x1D82B6,
        description: `**Check your DMs ${msg.author}!**`
    }})

}
```

If I were to do either "cb!ping" or "cb!purge," they would both work. When I do "cb!help" though I get this in the console:

```
[serve] message is not defined
[serve] CharleDarwins ran the command: help
```

I've done a bit of tinkering or whatever, but I can't figure out what it wants me to do. This is probably a pretty open ended question, but what does it want me to put and where? As always, my terminology is probably off, so I apologize, and thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: What's the reason for the duplicated code between `functions.js` and `commands/help.js`? looks like you're handling commands two different ways, the help function in `functions.js` does not accept a `message` parameter so it'll be undefined

Comment: Here ` message.author.send({embed})` and here ` message.channel.send(` you trying to get message but you're not getting it from anywhere, you can just pass it in the function `help: function(channel, message)`

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see. In your *command im trying to run* file, you do `let msg`, in your file, you're referencing `message`, instead of `msg`.

The reason message is undefined is because you haven't imported your file that references `message` from where-ever it comes from. For example this being `module.exports` or `export default`, at the bottom of the `message` file. Look at the top of your `functions` file, message isn't passed in, only `channel` is.

Just a bit of advice, run your file through `standard.js`, it's an NPM module :) - can be installed by doing `npm i standard`. Let me know how you get on!